# Contradiction tag

Tags: support, tags, flamewar

Seems like the [contradiction](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) tag could make for a nice synonym for [flamebait](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flamebait) can we nix it?

Unless used in the context of the prophecy of Simeon of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we can use a tag for claimed contradictions of the Bible. There are many, and I'd say they're a field of their own.

**I propose we rename and alias [contradiction](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) to the more describing and accurate [textual-discrepancies](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-discrepancies).**
*(props to @Caleb for suggesting that in the comments.)*

Comment: If anything [tag:biblical-contradiction] needs to be added or rather, [tag:claimed-biblical-contradiction].  But I don't think that's the way StackExchange works.  You'd need a stealth mod to go and execute that sort of change.

Comment: @PeterTurner: can't we just make tag synonyms to automatically force a certain tag instead of [tag:contradiction]?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done anything useful with tag synonyms before.

Comment: Just decide what the tag should be renamed to and if any synonyms (extra alias for the canonical tag) are and the mods can take care of it in short order. Our job is to settle on what we want.

Comment: How about [tag:textual-discrepancies]? I think this would help focus it on the actual text and not crazy tangent stuff. I don't think we need claimed or alleged or anything like that. That's for the question to settle.

Comment: @Caleb yes, that's better. Edited the proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I think there are valid uses for this tag.  For example [How did Judas die?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/768/how-did-judas-die).

Other questions that use that tag should probably be retagged, since it seems that the questioner was attempting to expose contradictions, but didn't reference any valid contradictions in the bible.  (Those are the ones that should be tagged [flame-bait](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flame-bait))

But I agree that [contradictions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradictions) can be valid and useful.  When it's not, it should be edited.